# Why are methods of extended interface not visible in class that implements extending interface?

Tags: java, generics, interface, java-8

I have an issue with the java.time API, specifically the LocalDate.

LocalDate implements ChronoLocalDate and this implements Comparable.

When I do something like

```
LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();
now.getClass().getInterfaces();
```

It only lists me the interfaces directly at LocalDate, but not the ones that are inherited by ChronoLocalDate. Why is this the case?

Add-On: My original issue is that I have a generic class working on types that implement comparable, but this obviously does not work with LocalDate as it does not implement Comparable directly.

Here is the definition of the generic class:

```
public final class Range<T extends Comparable<T> & Serializable> implements Serializable
```

What would I need to do to make this generic class definition work for LocalDate type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should't your definition look more like this:

```
static final class Range<T extends Comparable<? super T> &   
          Serializable> implements Serializable {
```

Comment: Great input thank you, I was aware that the definition needed to look different but it wasn't clear to me how to add this reference to the implemented interface. Nevertheless, do you know as well the answer to my first question (which is just a philosophical one for me) why the inherited interface methods are not retrieved by that?

Comment: @hecko84 because the javadoc says so? `Returns the interfaces directly implemented by the class or interface represented by this object`. There are ways to get them all; `guava` provides this via `TypeToken`.

Comment: Ok I see, sometimes reading helps, I just didn't look at that. Thanks for the tip regarding guava and for the generic definition anyway.